# How to replace object key?

Tags: javascript

I Have An Object. I need to replace/change the key name.

```
{ "waferProcessTimeDTOS" :[ { "processTime" : "2019-02-11T15:14:06.000+0000" , "waferId" : "Q844163" }, { "processTime" : "2019-02-11T15:14:06.000+0000" , "waferId" : "Q844163" } ]}
```

I need to change key name from 'processTime' to 'wafferTime'. Like below

```
{ "waferProcessTimeDTOS" :[ { "wafferTime" : "2019-02-11T15:14:06.000+0000" , "waferId" : "Q844163" }, { "wafferTime" : "2019-02-11T15:14:06.000+0000" , "waferId" : "Q844163" } ]}
```

Codes welcome.! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have multiple keys with the same name within the one object, the last one will always override the others

Comment: Post the codes in which you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a json first parse it with `JSON.parse` into a variable example `obj`

Then do:

```
obj.Fruit = obj.Task;
delete obj.Task;
```

Then stringify with `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: Kindly check my updated question. And help me solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Just apply those changes in place like Task to processName and so